# How to restrict users from creating new organization on Grafana

Tags: grafana

On a Grafana deployment if i create a user with the Editor role it can't perform administrative tasks but it can create a new organization and gain Administrative privileges on that organization. Is there a way to prevent roles from creating new Organizations?

Bellow you can see a snapshot of a user with the Editor role viewing the "New organization" action on the main menu on Grafana 3.1.0
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a global switch (all users will be affected, but admin)  in grafana's config file - [`allow_org_create`](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/#allow_org_create), by [default](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/conf/defaults.ini#L164) it's enabled.